# Loading GeoTiff to QGIS - nothing displays

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I have generated a GeoTIFF with CRS set to WGS 84:

```
geotransform=(xmin, xres, 0,ymax ,0, -yres)

output_raster = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(filename + ".tiff",ncols, nrows, 1 ,
                                                     gdal.GDT_CInt16)  # Open the file

output_raster.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)            # Specify its coordinates
srs = osr.SpatialReference()                           # Establish its coordinate encoding
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)                               # specifies WGS84 lat lon
output_raster.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())         # Exports coordinate system
                                                       # to the file
```

The TIFF loads and displays in ArcGIS with no issues.

In QGIS, I load the TIFF and it does not appear. I set the CRS for layer to WGS 84 (as a similar question suggested) but the TIFF still doesn't show (I've tried zooming to layer).

In the 'properties' for the TIFF, I can see the histogram of my data has the correct pixel value - so the data is definetly present.

Any other suggestions as to what might be causing this?

gdalinfo -stats output:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: LIIN50_202002201000.tiff
Size is 2688, 2016
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World"],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (90.000000000000000,30.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.023809523809524,-0.023809523809524)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  90.0000000,  30.0000000) ( 90d 0' 0.00"E, 30d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (  90.0000000, -18.0000000) ( 90d 0' 0.00"E, 18d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right ( 154.0000000,  30.0000000) (154d 0' 0.00"E, 30d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 154.0000000, -18.0000000) (154d 0' 0.00"E, 18d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      ( 122.0000000,   6.0000000) (122d 0' 0.00"E,  6d 0' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=2688x1 Type=CInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=184.000 Max=304.000 
  Minimum=184.000, Maximum=304.000, Mean=208.768, StdDev=21.274
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
  256 buckets from 183.765 to 304.235:
  455 0 2182 0 4421 0 8486 0 0 16487 0 20685 0 28397 0 105770 0 326829 0 405545 0 427383 0 332574 0 0 306874 0 269193 0 200719 0 196494 0 153691 0 146656 0 138483 0 130108 0 0 117253 0 112207 0 102442 0 87773 0 71599 0 78687 0 69754 0 61557 0 0 64424 0 54482 0 53089 0 50249 0 47437 0 41910 0 47780 0 42190 0 0 33457 0 34942 0 29986 0 26662 0 26287 0 26062 0 25272 0 24437 0 0 25596 0 24941 0 21413 0 26002 0 21721 0 25991 0 22639 0 21271 0 0 21444 0 20687 0 20940 0 19942 0 19999 0 17019 0 19536 0 16725 0 0 19420 0 17058 0 19532 0 16952 0 16083 0 16798 0 15814 0 17008 0 0 13238 0 17411 0 16229 0 14148 0 17353 0 13058 0 17201 0 13022 0 0 13439 0 13200 0 12181 0 12950 0 11837 0 12646 0 9428 0 12006 0 0 12843 0 9270 0 11583 0 9220 0 9611 0 11309 0 8193 0 8330 0 0 7304 0 6332 0 6447 0 6063 0 5480 0 4145 0 5701 0 4860 0 2788 0 0 4517 0 2968 0 2971 0 3934 0 2677 0 2620 0 2364 0 3187 0 0 1709 0 1628 0 1356 0 609 0 1027 0 843 0 696 0 350 0 0 527 0 215 0 39 0 44 
  Overviews: 1344x1008, 672x504, 336x252
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=304
    STATISTICS_MEAN=208.7677154195
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=184
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=21.274471655338
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
```

Comment: please add the `gdalinfo` output

Comment: What CRS is your project using? You can use hotkey ctrl + shift + P to find out. Layers having different coordinate reference systems can be examined in the same canvas thanks to project reprojecting them on the fly to project CRS. Thus, perhaps there is an issue between your project CRS and layer CRS. Try changing project CRS if this is the case.

Comment: What program did you generate the geotiff in and where is the world file and projection information stored?  ArcGIS may have created a world file with an X added on to it.  ArcGIS can read the information in the aux.xml to tell it how to display the raster instead of the world file, but other software wants the world file.  If you find a tifx file rename it to remove the x and see if that works.  You should also give the tif the proper projection.

Comment: Ian - I have attached gdalinfo output. Ville - CRS is set to WGS84 for the layer, I select "Set CRS from Project" and it's still not visible.

Comment: Run gdalinfo again as `gdalinfo -hist LIIN50_202002201000.tiff` for seeing the min/max values.

Comment: @johns - I generated it in Python using GDAL from numpy arrays. I see ArcGIS has produced a .tiff.ovr file and a .tiff.aux file but no sign of a .tifx file.

Comment: @johns in addition I have set the projection in my code, I'll add this to the question.

Comment: @dwright I should have said tfwx since the tif world file is tfw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I answered in this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351412/generated-geotiff-in-gdal-not-opening-in-imagemagick) the problem they had was with the type of the data they were trying to read, maybe ArcGIS does the conversion automatically when it sees a GDAL Data Type, but QGIS does not do this and doesn't give any indication that it can't read the data inside the GeoTIFF, even though it shows it in the histogram.

The "problem" can be seen or identified in the next 2 blocks:

```
output_raster = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(filename + ".tiff", ncols, nrows, 
                                                           1, gdal.GDT_CInt16) #Type is GDT_CInt16
```

where the type ends as `CInt16` in QGIS (or `CFloat32` as I was using).

[image]

Or you can see the data type of your bands using `gdalinfo`:

```
Band 1 Block=2688x1 Type=CInt16, ColorInterp=Gray  #*** Type is CInt16 ***
Min=184.000 Max=304.000 
Minimum=184.000, Maximum=304.000, Mean=208.768, StdDev=21.274
```

in this part you can see the data type of that band is `CInt16` too.

The solution is to convert the data type to one that both ArcGIS and QGIS can read (`Float32` or `Int16`):

```
data_type_code = gdal_array.NumericTypeCodeToGDALTypeCode(data.dtype)
output_raster = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(
                                               filename + ".tiff", ncols, nrows, 1, data_type_code)
```

Here we convert the numpy type to a GDAL type code based on the data the array (`data`) already has.

Now we should see the `Float32` or `Int16` or whatever type our data has:

[image]